# InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1,10] and labels shape [40]

Tags: python, keras, keras-tuner

I'm using Keras-Tuner to auto-identify the best parameters for my CNN. I am using Celeb_a dataset.

you can find the code I am using [here](https://bitbucket.org/mrjeancamargo1/keras-tuner1/src/master/CelebA_Tuner.py)
When I try to run it I get the error below.

> InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first
> dimension, got logits shape [1,10] and labels shape [40]
> [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
> (defined at
> C:\Users\admin-sepr\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\tuner.py:141)
> ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_953]

I have seen in other places that this could be down to using `loss="categorical_crossentropy",` when I compile the code and they recomended to try `loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",` instead.

when I do this I get the following error.

> InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable:
> logits_size=[64,380192] labels_size=[64,40]    [[node
> categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at
> C:\Users\admin-sepr\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\tuner.py:141)
> ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6830]

The function call stack is the following for both errors.

```
Function call stack:
train_function
```

My function train_function goes as following (full code available above):

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                                        dataframe=train_split,
                                        directory=celeba.images_folder,
                                        x_col='image_id',
                                        y_col=celeba.features_name,
                                        target_size=TARGET_SIZE,
                                        batch_size=64,
                                        class_mode='raw',
                                        dtype=tf.float32)
```

I tried the recommended in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591550/logits-and-labels-must-be-broadcastable-error-in-tensorflow-rnn) but didnt get any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your data you have loaded from the Celeb_A dataset is not compatible with the model that you are trying to train. From just scanning the code it looks like you need to change the number of nodes in your output dense layer. This number (which you currently have at 10 nodes) should match the number of labels you expect to predict. From the error, it looks like there are 40 labels that you are predicting but the model thinks there are only 10.

My best guess is to keep your loss as categorical cross-entropy and change your output dense layer to Dense(40) rather than Dense(10).

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly.

I had to change the output dense layer to Dense(40) rather than Dense(10). I also had issues with the activation layer which needed to be set to Activation('relu'), my batch size was wrong, it needed to be 1 for validation and  class_mode='raw' Once I made these changes it ran ok. 

Thank you